# Creating a package to keep track of tapes used

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

Thought I had followed creation pattern, but the body will not compile.  What I am trying to accomplish is to develop a package to run a procedrure periodically to determine at what time and date more than 15 are in use.. Oracle 11g.

The only other data that needs to go into the table beingg inserted into the sysdate.

```
      CREATE OR REPLACE 
PACKAGE TAPES_USED AS 
function TAPESCOUNT(count number) return number;
procedure INSERT_TAPES_COUNT(sysdate date, count NUMBER);
END TAPES_USED;
/

-----------------------------------------

CREATE OR REPLACE 
PACKAGE body TAPES_USED AS 
function TAPESCOUNT(count number) return number as count number;
begin
select count(*)
into
count
from DEV.TAPES_IN USE where count(*) > 15;
procedure INSERT_TAPES_COUNT(sysdate date, count NUMBER)as
begin
INSERT INTO  DEV.TAPES_USED VALUES
  (sysdate, count);
end INSERT_TAPES_COUNT;
END TAPES_USED;
/
```

Any help or suggestion anyone can offer will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE 
PACKAGE BODY tapes_used AS 
FUNCTION tapescount(in_ct NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER IS 
  ct NUMBER;
  BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*)
      INTO ct
      FROM dev.tapes_in_use;
    IF ct > in_ct THEN
      RETURN ct;
    ELSE
      RETURN NULL;
    END IF;
  END tapescount;

  PROCEDURE insert_tapes_count(sysdt date, ct NUMBER) IS
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO  dev.tapes_used VALUES (sysdt, ct);
  END insert_tapes_count;
END tapes_used;
/
```

You should refrain from using reserved words such as COUNT and SYSDATE for variable names (I don't know but that could be some of your compilation issues), so I've renamed them. Also, you forgot to END your function. I think you were missing an underscore in your table name in the FROM clause of the SELECT in your function, and you didn't have a RETURN statement in your function, which you must have.

Generally speaking, a function should accept one or more input parameters and return a single value. You're not making use of the input parameter in your function.  I've implemented a suggested parameter.

As Egor notes, this isn't a realistic function, and I'm not certain about your intent here. What is the function supposed to do?

Maybe you want your function to return the Date/Time your count was exceeded?  You could also combine everything into a single procedure:

```
PROCEDURE ck_tape_ct(min_tape_ct NUMBER) IS
  ct NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*)
    INTO ct
    FROM dev.tapes_in_use;
  IF ct > min_tape_ct THEN
    INSERT INTO dev.tapes_used VALUES(SYSDATE, ct);
  END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Edited again. However, I'm only making a wild guess about what this function is supposed to do.

Comment: Use the procedure I provided.

Comment: Just a note to say that if the possible number of records counted exceeds in_ct by enough to have a performance impact due to having to count them all, adding "where rownum <= in_ct+1" would be beneficial.